# a simple fork program

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
  pid_t child_pid;
  printf ("the main program process ID is %d\n", (int) getpid());
  child_pid = fork () ;
  if (child_pid != 0) 
  {
    printf ("this is the parent process, with id %d\n", (int) getpid ());
    printf ("the child's process ID is %d\n",(int) child_pid );
  }
  else
    printf ("this is the child process, with id %d\n", (int) getpid ());
  return 0;
}
```

I have written a simple fork program to create a process , when I run the program I get the output as follows :

```
the main program process ID is 3322
this is the child process , with ID 0
```

Now my point is , why isn't the `if` block getting executed as in, in the parent process the return value of `fork()` is not equal to `0` so why am I not getting any output for the `if` block ?

Comment: @Ishmeet that's not the way fork works.

Comment: I just tested this on a Debian 7 and Mac OSX 19.9 platform, and they both do exactly what they're supposed to. Put a wait(NULL); in your parent-block just for kicks. Its seems your parent process io is being redirected or squelched after the fork. strange.

Comment: Tested it in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. It worked as it should. Your results are very strange indeed. What OS/version and compiler/version do you use?

Comment: Did you run your program like this: `./a.out > out-file`?

Comment: first i did this `gcc -o fork fork.c` then I did this `./fork`

Comment: Here's what i get:

    the main program process ID is 24563
    this is the parent process, with id 24563
    the child's process ID is 24573
    the main program process ID is 24563
    this is the child process, with id 24573

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: see http://ideone.com/pgJ5pA

Comment: So what do you get if you slip a `wait(NULL);` above the first output in the parent block. Just curious.

Comment: It is not working even with the `wait(NULL)` also :(

Comment: I don't know how , but I restarted the system and it worked , strange !

Comment: I have no explanation for this weird behaviour

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Can you get the **exact** result every time you run your program? If you can, please post the exact command you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code have at least two problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    printf ("the main program process ID is %d\n", (int) getpid());
    child_pid = fork () ;
    if (child_pid > 0) 
    {
        printf ("this is the parent process, with id %d\n", (int) getpid ());
        printf ("the child's process ID is %d\n",(int) child_pid );
    }
    else if (child_pid == 0)
        printf ("this is the child process, with id %d\n", (int) getpid ());
    else
        printf ("fork failed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

1. It did not flush the output buffer after the first `printf()`.

   If the output of this program is redirected to a file, the output will become block buffered, then the output of this `printf()` **may or may not** be written to the output file, therefore, the output file could be five or four lines (actually, most of them are five lines).

   Add a `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf()` can fix this problem.
2. The parent process terminated before the child process.

   In this case, once or twice in several thousands of runs of this program, the output of the child process is lost, the output file only has three lines. But after that `fflush()` be added, the output file should be four lines.

   **I do not really understand why this happens, or whether it is correct.** But fortunately, it is quite easy to fix. Add a `wait(NULL);` after the third `printf()` is enough.

---

Here is some very helpful explanation from [Art](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939410/art):

1. POSIX mandates that the file descriptors in the child process after fork point to the same file descriptions (file descriptions are not the same thing as file descriptors). The file descriptions contain (among others) the file offset. printf will eventually go through write to write out its output and write is guaranteed to atomically update the file offset and write out the data. So redirecting output in a forking program is safe as long as the program doesn't seek (which you're not supposed to do on stdout and printf definitely shouldn't).
2. references that didn't fit in the previous comment: [file description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_254), [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html).

Comment: POSIX mandates that the file descriptors in the child process after fork point to the same file descriptions (file descriptions are not the same thing as file descriptors). The file descriptions contain (among others) the file offset. `printf` will eventually go through `write` to write out its output and `write` is guaranteed to atomically update the file offset and write out the data. So redirecting output in a forking program is safe as long as the program doesn't seek (which you're not supposed to do on stdout and `printf` definitely shouldn't).

Comment: references that didn't fit in the previous comment: [file description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_254), [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)

Comment: @Art If I redirect the output of that program to a file, sometimes that output file does include less than 5 lines of text, but no mixed lines, only some whole lines are missing. You may want to test it by yourself. BTW, you may need to run that program hundreds of time to reproduce this phenomenon.

Comment: Then something in your operating system is broken. Or more likely, you're counting the lines in the file before the second process has exited (since the example code here doesn't `wait` properly). I've run this a few thousands times and it's behaving correctly. If this was a buffering problem in stdio it would behave in a deterministic way, but stdout is always line buffered, so it should be ok. Two forked processes writing to the same file is perfectly defined and has been since the dawn of unix. Otherwise redirecting output from a shell script or make wouldn't work, which it always does.

Comment: @Art Redirecting the output of this program will reveal at least two problems of this code: 1. it does not flush the output buffer before `fork()`, so the contents of first `printf()` could be output once or twice; 2. the parent does not wait its child before it exits, in this case, the output of child process may be lost. Although **I does not know why it happens, or whether this is correct**, it is quite easy to fix, add a `wait(NULL);` after the third `printf()` is enough.